# Javascript passing parameters from form to function --> update DB

Tags: javascript, sqlite

can anyone help please. I have a form generated dynamically, when it is submitted it should send values to a function and add them back to a database. I'm having real problems getting this to work, it seems simple: 1. Form --> 2. submit received --> 3. update function. The code is below:

Dynamically generated form:

```
   function renderResults(tx, rs) {
    e = $('#status');
    e.html("");
    for(var i=0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
      r = rs.rows.item(i);
  var f = $("<form>" +
"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rowId\" value=\"" + r.id + "\" />" +
"<input value=\"" + r.name + "\" name=\"name\" />" +
"<input value=\"" + r.amount + "\" name=\"amount\" />" +
"<input type=\"submit\" />" +
"</form>");
e.append("id: " + r.id, f);
f.submit(function(e)
{
updateRecord(this.rowId.value, this.name.value, this.amount.value);
});

        }
  }
```

Handles the form submit and passes to function:

```
$('#theform').submit(function() {
updateRecord($('#thename').val(), $('#theamount').val());

});
```

Function to set values:

```
function updateRecord(id, name, amount) {
db.transaction(function(tx) {

       tx.executeSql('UPDATE groupOne SET (name, amount) VALUES (?, ?) WHERE id=?', [name, amount, id], renderRecords);

  });
}
```

The DB update code has the id set to 4 as a test just to see if anything happens to row 4, i've been fiddling with this line for ages to get it to work. If i set it to:

```
tx.executeSql('UPDATE groupOne SET name = 4, amount = 5 WHERE id=?', [id], renderRecords);
```

it will work with set values, but can someone help me get the form values into it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the row id in your jQuery selector.  You are passing:

```
$('#thename').val();
```

But your field has an id of `"thename" + r["id"]`:

```
'<input type="text" ... id="thename' + r['id'] + '" ...>'
```

You need to get your value by passing the full input id.

```
$("#thename" + rowId).val();
```

**Edit:**  Looking more closely at your code, I notice you are creating multiple forms with the same id, which is invalid html.  I see now that you've got one form per record.  Good, just lose the id from the form and its inputs.  Instead, use names for the inputs.

```
var f = $("<form>" +
    "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rowId\" value=\"" + r.id + "\" />" +
    "<input name=\"name\" />" +
    "<input name=\"amount\" />" +
    "<input type=\"submit\" />" +
    "</form>");
e.append("id: " + r.id, f);
f.submit(function(e)
{
    updateRecord(this.rowId.value, this.name.value, this.amount.value);
});
```

Comment: Good spot, thanks. I've been looking at this for too long. How should this be used with the updateRecord function?   function updateRecord(thename, theamount) { ?

Comment: @m1sco - Do you want to update every record?  Sounds like you'll want to loop through the records and call updateRecord for each row in `rs`.

Comment: i was trying to achieve updating an individual record at a time if thats possible? apologies if im not explaining it very well, source is here: http://pastebin.com/NhB4Ue8q

Comment: @gilly3 thankyou for your help, i edited the question to show the changes. I put the values into the form inputs to load the existing values, will that cause a problem? So am I correct in saying the form handler is no longer needed, the form values are passed directly to the updateRecord function? It still doesn't work because I have no idea what form the updateRecord function should take now.

Comment: @m1sco - You don't need the `$('#theform').submit(function() { ... });`, but it shouldn't cause any problems.  Is it still not working?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: @gilly3 nope, but its close. I tested it with an alert to check the values are going through to the function. It must be my update statement:     function updateRecord(id, name, amount) {
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
//           tx.executeSql('UPDATE groupOne SET (name, amount) VALUES (?, ?) WHERE id=?', [name, amount, id]);
//  alert('name ' + name + ' amount ' + amount + '.');

  renderRecords();
  
  }); 
  }

Comment: hmmm, thankyou for all your help @gilly3. I've got it working with:  tx.executeSql('UPDATE groupOne SET name="'+name+'", amount ='+amount+' WHERE id='+id+''); but its extremely temperamental like one in every 5 or so submissions of the form will stick. I will investigate in the morning. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @m1sco - Besides using `alert()` to debug your code, I'd highly recommend becoming familiar with the JavaScript debuggers that are built-in to most browsers.  For Chrome, hit ctrl+shift+j to open the dev tools and click the "scripts" tab.  In IE, hit F12.  In Firefox, install firebug, then hit F12.  You'll be able to set breakpoints, step through the code, examine variables, and execute scripts.  You can replace your alerts with `console.log()`.

Comment: @gilly3 I was actually looking for exactly that, i had no idea it already existed in chrome